# What is the difference between a holonomic and an omnidirectional robot?

Tags: mobile-robot

I have seen the usage of the term "omnidirectional" in robotics, but I have not found a (precise) definition.

In the chapter [Omni-Directional Robots](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-70534-5_9) from the book "Embedded Robotics", it is stated:

> In contrast, a holonomic or omnidirectional robot is capable of driving in any direction

which seems to indicate that these words are synonyms.

What's an omnidirectional robot? What is the difference between a holonomic and an omnidirectional robot (if any)? What are examples of omnidirectional and holonomic robots (or other objects)?

Answer (score 11):

[Holonomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_(robotics)) is a precise mathematical term; one definition is velocity constraints can be integrated into the form
$$\begin{align}
f(q1,q2,...,t) = 0. 
\end{align}$$

Roughly, that means the controllable degrees of freedom at any instant matches the total degrees of freedom for the robot. By this definition, a train is holonomic b/c it has one controllable degree of freedom (speed) and one motion degree of freedom (position along the track). However, most people would likely *not* consider a train to be omnidirectional.

Note that a car is nonholonomic. At any give instant you have two controllable degrees of freedom (speed and steer angle) but three motion degrees of freedom (x, y, and orientation).